# Bluetooth Touchpad for my bluetooth keyboard

Tags: touchpad

I would like to have a touchpad about the size of the one on typical laptop to put right below my bluetooth keyboard.  My bluetooth keyboard is compact and JIS(Japanese) and rather unique so I need something that fits ideally in that space.

Comment: It appears that Bluetooth track-pads are not common and [VERY expensive](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAC917908679&cm_re=trackpad-_-9SIAC917908679-_-Product). It would be significantly cheaper to purchase a wireless usb track pad instead. [How about something like this?](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=9SIAAWS6RJ6935)

Comment: @BennettYeo I would like something smaller preferably otherwise yes.  Money is not a concern.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the smallest and most reasonably priced option I can find. We're kind of delving into a niche market here. The higher end wireless/RF/Bluetooth track pads only get larger.